# Define embargo settings in import process - DSpace

Tags: dspace

I originally posted this question on the dspace-tech listserv, but haven't received any definitive answers.

Is it possible to define embargo settings (e.g., a “lift date”) as part of a batch import process in DSpace 3.0+ (e.g., using the Simple Archive Format ingest process or the AIP or CSV ingest processes)?

I am already familiar with—and am hoping to avoid—the “pre-3.0” embargo functionality.

The "newish" 3.0 embargo functionality is described here: https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC3x/Embargo.

I searched for this issue online, and came across this thread: http://dspace.2283337.n4.nabble.com/KE1019161-Embargo-settings-on-item-import-td4660719.html. Helix84’s post at Jan 03, 2013; 7:38am touches directly on this issue, but seems incorrect as far as I can tell (AIP mets.xml doesn’t seem to describe embargo settings).

I’ve created an item in my test repository (DSpace 3.2) using the xmlui interface and defined an embargo for a bitstream using the “Simple Embargo/UploadWithEmbargoStep” process. I’ve confirmed that the item was added successfully, and that the policy restrictions are enforced for anonymous users.

I then exported the item as an AIP, SAF, and CSV (using the various export mechanisms). None of the exported data (AIP’s mets.xml, the SAF files, or the CSV) seemed to have any information about my embargo.

Is there a way to include this information in the import process, or would I have to set this manually in xmlui or write a SQL script to add these embargo policies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, none of the pre-DSpace 4 import mechanisms support ingestion of bitstream policies.

DSpace 4 AIP import and export supports the new, policy based embargo's. 
Reference: https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-1514

This means that the METS export will now contain the embargo policy dates. For example, here is a policy where the bitstream will become available for public download on Jan 1st 2014:

```
<rightsMD ID="rightsMD_28">
   <mdWrap MDTYPE="OTHER" OTHERMDTYPE="METSRIGHTS">
    <xmlData xmlns:rights="http://cosimo.stanford.edu/sdr/metsrights/" xsi:schemaLocation="http://cosimo.stanford.edu/sdr/metsrights/ http://cosimo.stanford.edu/sdr/metsrights.xsd"><rights:RightsDeclarationMD xmlns:rights="http://cosimo.stanford.edu/sdr/metsrights/" RIGHTSCATEGORY="LICENSED">
  <rights:Context rpName="" in-effect="false" start-date="2014-01-01" CONTEXTCLASS="GENERAL PUBLIC">
    <rights:Permissions DISCOVER="true" DISPLAY="true" MODIFY="false" DELETE="false" />
  </rights:Context>
</rights:RightsDeclarationMD>
```

This export was created using the AIP export

./dspace packager -d -e me@me.com -i 123456789/10728 ~/Desktop/export.zip -t METS

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks David, based on your feedback I tried to provide a more elaborate answer.

Comment: Accepted, although METS isn't an ideal import format (for me at least), compared with the SAF and CSV imports. I ended up modifying `ItemImport.java` to allow me to add the "start-date" metadata to the `contents` text file.

Comment: Also, with DSpace 4.1, I had to run the AIP export command with `-t AIP` (not METS), to get it to include the `rights:Context` field...